# How can I increment a numerical part of a string between two characters using sed or awk or grep?

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep, cat

I have a string like **X1.7_RC02.20170811110948** and I need to increase only the number between **RC** and the next point, example:

Original string:

```
X1.7_RC02.20170811110948
```

Incremented string:

```
X1.7_RC03.20170811110948
```

How can I increase in 1 (or more this value)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find/replace and increment a matched number with sed/awk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14348432/how-to-find-replace-and-increment-a-matched-number-with-sed-awk)

Comment: @RavinderSingh13,  the edit should not contain asterisks `*`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `GNU` sed

```
sed -r 's/(.*)(RC0?)([1-9]+)(\..*)/echo "\1\2$((\3+1))\4"/e' <<<X1.7_RC02.20170811110948
```

Answer (score 4):

with GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match():

```
$ awk 'match($0,/(.*RC)([^.]+)(.*)/,a){$0=sprintf("%s%02d%s",a[1],a[2]+1,a[3])} 1' file
X1.7_RC03.20170811110948
```

Answer (score 1):

Considering your data is same as shown example then try with following awk once too and let me know if this helps you.

```
awk '{val=$0;gsub(/.*RC|\..*/,"",val);val=sprintf("%02d",++val);sub(/RC[0-2]+/,"RC"val);print}'  Input_file
```

Or if you have a string then you could print it's value and could run above command like:

```
echo "$var" | awk '{val=$0;gsub(/.*RC|\..*/,"",val);val=sprintf("%02d",++val);sub(/RC[0-2]+/,"RC"val);print}'
```

Answer (score 1):

***awk*** solution:

Initial string:

```
s="X1.7_RC02.20170811110948"
```

---

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FS=OFS="_RC"}{ n=substr($2,1,2); print $1,sprintf("%02.f",n+1) substr($2,3)}' <<< $s
```

The output:

```
X1.7_RC03.20170811110948
```