# find and replace multiple patterns in a specific csv column with sed

Tags: csv, awk, sed

I have a csv file like this:

```
2018-May-17 21:33:16,VF-AUDI-prod,Start:2018-May-17:End:2018-May-19
2018-May-17 21:34:15,VF-AUDI-prod,Start:2018-May-17:End:2018-May-19
2018-May-17 21:35:17,VF-AUDI-prod,Start:2018-May-17:End:2018-May-19
```

I need to convert only the first column into a `YYYYMMDDHHmmss` format like this:

```
20180517213316,VF-AUDI-prod,Start:2018-May-17:End:2018-May-19
20180517213415,VF-AUDI-prod,Start:2018-May-17:End:2018-May-19
20180517213517,VF-AUDI-prod,Start:2018-May-17:End:2018-May-19
```

How can I achieve this with sed without modifying the other columns?

Comment: Do you already know how to do *any part of this?* If you had the first column alone, would you know how to modify it?

Comment: Why awk why sed? This will be much easier with Python, Perl, C, C++, Java, Ruby...

Comment: Can you tell us how the other months are written? Are they all 3 letters, or are they full?

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk -F'[- :,]' '{
    t = $1 sprintf("%02d",(index("JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec",$2)+2)/3) $3 $4 $5 $6
    sub(/[^,]+/,t)
}1' file
20180517213316,VF-AUDI-prod,Start:2018-May-17:End:2018-May-19
20180517213415,VF-AUDI-prod,Start:2018-May-17:End:2018-May-19
20180517213517,VF-AUDI-prod,Start:2018-May-17:End:2018-May-19
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do the replacement. But both of the two ways need a **help shell script**.

**PHP version**

`sed -r 's/([^,]*),(.*)/echo $(echo "\1"|.\/php.sh),\2/e' file`

php.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

read str
php -r "echo date('YmdHis', strtotime('$str'));"
```

**bash version**

`sed -r 's/([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([0-9]{1,2})[[:space:]]*([0-9]{1,2}):([0-9]{1,2}):([0-9]{1,2}),(.*)/echo \1$(echo "\2"\|.\/help.sh)\3\4\5\6,\7/e' file`

help.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

read str

case $str in
    Jan) MON=01 ;;
    Feb) MON=02 ;;
    Mar) MON=03 ;;
    Apr) MON=04 ;;
    May) MON=05 ;;
    Jun) MON=06 ;;
    Jul) MON=07 ;;
    Aug) MON=08 ;;
    Sep) MON=09 ;;
    Oct) MON=10 ;;
    Nov) MON=11 ;;
    Dec) MON=12 ;;
esac

echo $MON
```

Output:

```
20180517213316,VF-AUDI-prod,Start:2018-May-17:End:2018-May-19
20180517213415,VF-AUDI-prod,Start:2018-May-17:End:2018-May-19
20180517213517,VF-AUDI-prod,Start:2018-May-17:End:2018-May-19
```

For more information about the use of `echo` embedded in `sed`, you can go [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14348899/5209502)

Answer (score 0):

Following `awk` may help you on same.

```
awk -F"," '
BEGIN{
   num=split("jan,feb,mar,apr,may,jun,jul,aug,sept,oct,nov,dec",array,",");
   for(i=1;i<=num;i++){
      month[array[i]]=sprintf("%02d",i)}
}
{
   split($1,a,"[- ]");
   a[2]=month[tolower(a[2])];
   $1=a[1] a[2] a[4];
   gsub(/:/,"",$1)
}
1' OFS=","   Input_file
```

***Explanation of code:***

```
awk -F"," '                                                                ##Setting field separator as comma here or lines.
BEGIN{                                                                     ##Starting BEGIN section for awk here.
   num=split("jan,feb,mar,apr,may,jun,jul,aug,sept,oct,nov,dec",array,",");##Using split to create a month names array and its length is stored in num variable.
   for(i=1;i<=num;i++){                                                    ##Starting a for loop from variable value i=1 to till value of num here.
      month[array[i]]=sprintf("%02d",i)}                                   ##Creating an array month whose index is array value with index i and value is variable i.
}
{                                                                          ##Starting main section here which will be executed during Input_file reading by awk.
   split($1,a,"[- ]");                                                     ##Using split to split $1 into array a whose delimiter are space and - in that line.
   a[2]=month[tolower(a[2])];                                              ##Setting 2nd value of array a to value of month array, to get months into digit format.
   $1=a[1] a[2] a[4];                                                      ##Re-creating first field with values of first, second and third values of array a.
   gsub(/:/,"",$1)                                                         ##globally substituting colon with NULL in first colon.
}
1                                                                          ##Using 1 here to print the current line.
' OFS="," Input_file                                                    ##Setting output field separator as comma and mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F, '{ gsub(/:| /, "", $1); 
    x=(match("JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec", substr($1,6,3))+2)/3;
    x=x>9?x:0x; gsub(/-.*-/, x, $1) }1' OFS=, infile
```

Output:

```
20180517213316,VF-AUDI-prod,Start:2018-May-17:End:2018-May-19
20180517213415,VF-AUDI-prod,Start:2018-May-17:End:2018-May-19
20180517213517,VF-AUDI-prod,Start:2018-May-17:End:2018-May-19
```

#### How it works

- this `-F,` defines what delimiter is separated fields.
- this `gsub(/:| /, "", $1)` removes *spaces* and *colons* from the first field.
- this `substr($1,6,3)` return the ***month name*** from first field
- this `match("JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec", substr($1,6,3))` returns the first character position (Index) of the ***month name*** begins in string of all *month names* `JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec`*= 13*. the result of this `match(...)` will always one of these *1, 4, 7, 10, 13, 16, 19, 22, 25, 28, 31, 34*; now we got *13* and since each *month name* is in length of *3* we should find a way how to return *5* in result so we added *2* to the result to point the position to the end of matched *month name* then divide into *3* `13+2/3=5`.
- this `x=x>9?x:0x` prepending a *`0`* to the number above if its less than *10*
- this `gsub(/-.*-/, x, $1)` replaces the match between hyphens which is *month name* with the value of `x` in first field only.
- this `1` is always true condition and causes to print the line *awk* read
- this `OFS=,` is setting ***O**utput **F**eild **S**eperator* back to the *comma* `,`.

Answer (score 0):

Sed one-liner :

```
$ cat file.csv | sed 's/^\([[:digit:]]*\)-\([^ ]*\)\(.*\)/\2-\1\3/g' | sed 's/\([^,]*\),\(.*\)/echo $(date -d "\1" +%Y%m%d%H%M%S ),\2/e'
```

**Explanation**

- Convert %Y-%m-%d to %m-%d-%Y format in order to be consumed by date -d
- Use sed to substitute only the first column.
- Use date's -d command to read the date input.
- Use date's +%Y%m%d%H%M%S to print the output

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
m="Jan01Feb02Mar03Apr04May05Jun06Jul07Aug08Sep09Oct10Nov11Dec12"
sed -E 's/$/\n'"$m"'/;s/-(...)-(..) (..):(..):(.*)\n.*\1(..).*/\6\2\3\4\5/' file
```

Append a lookup table to the end of each line and using pattern matching, grouping and back references, transform the first column to the required specification.

Alternative, less messy and more efficient:

```
cat <<\! | sed -Ef - file
1{x;s/^/Jan01Feb02Mar03Apr04May05Jun06Jul07Aug0Sep09Oct10Nov11Dec12/;x}
G
s/-(...)-(..) (..):(..):(.*)\n.*\1(..).*/\6\2\3\4\5/
P
d
!
```

Comment: @EdMorton thanks, changed `l` for lookup to `m` for month, also shortened the original solution (no need to the match the year) and added another alternative using a piped here-document.