# Why is this regex missing quotes?

Tags: regex, sed

I'm trying to use sed to increment a version number in a conf file. The version number is of this form:
`MENDER_ARTIFACT_NAME = "release-6"`.

Using the following:

`sed -r 's/(.*)(release\-)([0-9]*)(.*)/echo "\1\2$((\3+1))\4"/ge'`

The result, is this:
`MENDER_ARTIFACT_NAME = release-7`

I.E. it works, but it misses the quotes. I've checked the regex docs, and (.*) should match all non newline characters, any number of times, so the first should match everything, including the quote, before `release-6`, and the second should match everything, including the quote, after `release-6`. Instead, it seems to drop the quotes completely. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When you use solutions other people created, the nice thing to do is to refer to them. In this case, you took code from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14348899.

Comment: I did, yes. I didn’t realise that single lines of bash commands required attribution. Sorry.

Comment: @revo that makes sense, thanks. If you want to add it as an answer, I’ll accept it

Comment: I don't know about "require attribution", that's not even my point. I said *"the nice thing to do"*. As in, "I din't come up with this, I took it from here." It should not be legally required to do what's decent.

Comment: I didn't realise that such things were required for 'decency'. I've never expected to have single lines of my code credited, but if others do, then I shall do so in future. Consider me suitably contrite.

Comment: Not related to the question: *`release\-`* - outside of a character class, the dash (`-`) is just a regular character, there is no need to escape it.

Comment: @axiac Good point, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html):

> the `e` flag executes the substitution result as a shell command...

which means quotation marks are there for showing a bunch of characters. I.e try `echo MENDER_ARTIFACT_NAME = "release-6"`. You should add escaped quotation marks in echo statement manually:

```
sed -r 's/^(.*)(release\-)([0-9]+)/echo "\1\\"\2$((\3+1))\\""/ge'
```