# Linux: Find and increase version

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sed

How do I get the version number from a file and increase the version with 1?
I would like to store the version to a variable, increase it with one en save the new version in the file.

Let's say I have a simple config file (application.config) like this:

```
[section1]
Some = variables

[Version]
version = 1.0
```

The version always starts with "version = " (without the quotes, I added them to demonstrate the space after =).
I would like to:

- Change 1.0 to 1.1 (1.9 should get 1.10, 1.99 should get 1.100 etc).
- Store 1.1 to a variable to use it in another part of my script.

I tried it with sed:

```
sed -i -r 's/version = [0-9]+.[0-9]+/version = $Version/I' application.config
```

This works if I manually enter $version, hoe do I get it from the file itself?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between single and double quotes in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find/replace and increment a matched number with sed/awk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14348432/how-to-find-replace-and-increment-a-matched-number-with-sed-awk)

Comment: I came across that question in my search. But I can't get that example to work in my situation. If I use `sed -r 's/(.*)(\version =)([0-9]+)(.*)/echo "\1\2$((\3+1))\4"/ge' application.config` it stays 1.0.

Comment: Using `s/.../.../e` is a *really* bad idea -- same family of security issues as awk's shell-invocation support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
version=$(sed -nE 's/version = ([0-9]+.[0-9]+)/\1/Ip' application.config)
lastnumber=$((${version##*.}+1))
newversion=${version%.*}.$lastnumber
sed -i -E "s/version = [0-9]+.[0-9]+/version = $newversion/I" application.config
```

Notice that I have changed `-r` to `-E` in your `sed`. They are equivalent but the latter is understood by other `sed` implementations.

Answer (score 1):

This might help you:

```
grep "version = [0-9]*.[0-9]*" <filename> | awk -F '.' '{print $1 "." 1+$2}'
grep -E "version = [0-9]+.[0-9]+" <filename> | awk -F '.' '{print $1 "." 1+$2}'
```

First search for the word "version", then split the line in two pieces, based on the dot separator, and add "1" to the second part.

Remark : the `-E` is needed in order for the plus-signs to work.

Comment: ` awk -F. '/^version = [0-9]\.[0-9]/{print $1 FS $2+1}' config.txt`

Answer (score 0):

Just to show another way that you should avoid, because it is illegible and unmanageable.
Since you know the prefix you can use grep's perl-regexp engine to extract the
whole version, then replace the dot with a comma and bash will add the digit after the comma without extracting it in a further variable.

```
sed -E -i "s/\.[[:digit:]]+/\.$(($(grep -Po "(?<=version\s=\s)\d+\.\d+$" conf.ini | sed "s/\./,/g")+1))/g" conf.ini
```