# How to increment a number at the end of a line with bash?

Tags: sed

I have a text file that looks like this:

```
qwerty=1.8
asdfg=15.9
zxcvb=144.99
```

I managed to replace a specific version with another specific version using sed:

```
sed s/asdfg=15.9/asdfg=15.10/ file
```

But how can i make it dynamic? My end goal is a command that i can use with argument "asdfg" and it will update the line asdfg=15.9 to asdfg=15.10 without me having to know the version.

Comment: please check this url https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14348432/how-to-find-replace-and-increment-a-matched-number-with-sed-awk

Answer (score 2):

With `GNU awk`:

```sh
$ # adds 1 to entire number after =
$ awk 'match($0, /(asdfg=)(.+)/, m){$0 = m[1] m[2]+1} 1' file
qwerty=1.8
asdfg=16.9
zxcvb=144.99

$ # adds 1 after the decimal point
$ awk 'match($0, /(asdfg=[0-9]+\.)(.+)/, m){$0 = m[1] m[2]+1} 1' file
qwerty=1.8
asdfg=15.10
zxcvb=144.99
```

Here `match` is used to separate out the prefix string and the number to be incremented. The results are available from `m` array.

---

With `perl`

```sh
$ perl -pe 's/asdfg=\K.+/$&+1/e' file
qwerty=1.8
asdfg=16.9
zxcvb=144.99
```

The `e` flag allows you to use Perl code in replacement section. `\K` is used here to avoid `asdfg=` showing up in matched portion. `$&` will have the matched portion, which is the number after `asdfg=` in this case.

To change only after the decimal point:

```sh
$ perl -pe 's/asdfg=\d*\.\K.+/$&+1/e' ip.txt
qwerty=1.8
asdfg=15.10
zxcvb=144.99
```

Use `perl -i -pe` to write the changes back to `file`. Use `-i.bkp` to create backups.